# Style sheet showing all styles for all HTML elements on the site?

Tags: html, css, styling

So when a website has a specific page which shows every html element with it's styling for the site, to share amongst the dev team so the css of the site is in unison. So the page would literally just lsit all the html elements.

I know of them, I've done them myself but what are they called?!

Thanks!

Comment: Style Guide, Style Template, UI Guide... take your pick.

Comment: Style guide! That's what it's called! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to make a style guide. like http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ has for example

Comment: Haha I remember now! Thanks, had a senior moment! :P